# Proof of Stirling numbers of the second kind formula

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers, set-partition

I have been looking for mathematical proof for the expression to find the Stirling numbers of the second, $S(m,n)$. But I find it hard to understand.

**My Attempt**

We have two sets $A$ and $B$ wth $N(A)=m$ and $N(B)=n$, and we need to find the total number of onto functions from $A$ to $B$.

Step 1:

We will partition the set $A$ with $m$ elements into $n$ blocks (nonempty subsets) and each of these blocks are then connected to each $n$ elements of the set $B$. Each block has $n!$ ways to connect with the set $B$, i.e, One such partition has $n!$ onto functions. Thus,

$\#\{f:A\to{B}:f \text{ is onto}\}$ = $n!$ $\times$ Number of partitons of the $m$ element set $A$ into $n$ nonempty blocks.

Take, Number of partitons of the $m$ element set $A$ into $n$ nonempty subsets =$S(m,n)$, Stirling numbers of the second.

> $\#\{f:A\to{B}:f \text{ is onto}\}$=$n!\times S(m,n)$

Step 2:

$\#\{f:A\to B\}=n^m$

$$
\#\{f:A\to{B}:f\text{ is onto}\}=n^m-\Bigg[ \#\text{ of onto functions from $A$ to $B$ whose range misses atleast one element of $B$} \Bigg]
$$
Lets take, $\#\text{ of onto functions from $A$ to $B$ whose range misses atleast one element of $B$}\equiv \#\text{ of onto }\geq{1}$

$$
\#\{f:A\to{B}:f\text{ is onto}\}=\binom{n}{0}n^m-\bigg[\#\text{ of onto }\geq{1}\bigg]\\=\binom{n}{0}n^m-\Bigg[\binom{n}{1}(n-1)^m-\bigg(\#\text{ of onto }\geq{2}\bigg)\Bigg]\\=\binom{n}{0}n^m-\Bigg[\binom{n}{1}(n-1)^m-\bigg(\binom{n}{2}(n-2)^m-\Big[\#\text{ of onto }\geq{3}\Big]\bigg)\Bigg]\\=\binom{n}{0}n^m-\Bigg[\binom{n}{1}(n-1)^m-\bigg(\binom{n}{2}(n-2)^m-\Big[........\# \text{ of onto }\geq{n-1}\Big]\bigg)\Bigg]\\=\binom{n}{0}n^m-\binom{n}{1}(n-1)^m
+\binom{n}{2}(n-2)^m-\binom{n}{3}(n-3)^m+\binom{n}{4}(n-4)^m-.......\binom{n}{n-1}1^m=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(n-k)^m
$$

> $$
> \#\{f:A\to{B}:f \text{ is onto}\}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(n-k)^m=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(n-k)^m
> $$

From Step 1 and Step 2,
$$
\#\{f:A\to{B}:f\text{ is onto}\}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(n-k)^m=n!\times S(m,n)
$$
The Stirling numbers of the second kind 
$$
S(m,n)=\frac{1}{n!}.\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(n-k)^m
$$

Can I consider this as a well defined simple proof for the Stirling number of the second kind formula ?. Someone give a better explanation particularly for Step 2 ?

Comment: "# of onto functions from A to B whose range misses atmost one elements of B"--why at most, and not at least?

Comment: @Useless Suppose we have $n=3$. Then, $\#\{f:A\to B:f \text{ is onto}\}$=$3^m$$-$Other combination of onto functions for n'=2,1.ie, $3^m$$-$$\#$ of onto functions from $A$ to $B$ whose range misses atmost one elements of $B$=$3^m$$-$$\bigg(\binom{3}{1}2^m-\big(\#$ of onto functions from $A$ to $B$ whose range misses atmost 2 elements of $B\big)\bigg)$. Hope i made my point clear

Comment: @Useless ohh srry it is "atleast", not atmost.. i got confused myself i guess. pls check i made the correction.

Comment: are you obliged to go through the definition with Binomials ? It would be much simpler to prove that the recurrence formula for S(n,m) corresponds to that of the *surjections* from $A$ to $B$.

Comment: @GCab could u pls explain more pls.

Comment: I mean to say that I do not catch exactly your final goal. The formula $S(m,n)=\frac{1}{n!}.\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(n-k)^m$ can be demonstrated in many ways: your step 2 is one of the ways, and it is ok. What is then exactly your question?